# Converting object to jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebar js and i have created a helper.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('str', function(....) {
    el = $(this);
    console.log(el);
});
```

when i check in firebug el will be assigned an object in this format

```
 Object { title="Title1", day="Fri", more...}
```

But it is basically a li. How can i get the object as a li so that i can perform operations on that.[image]

Comment: Do you mean to say you want the html of the li ? In that case use $(this).html() to get the markup

Comment: If you want to get the plain DOM node (`var el = this;`), just *don't wrap the element in a jQuery object*.

Comment: no not html .. but as a li object so that i can do operations like el.find('div') ... etc

Comment: You can't do operations like `el.find()` if `el` is an `li` object, only if `el` is a jQuery object. But the Firebug results you show don't look like a DOM element _or_ a jQuery object.

Comment: P.S. What do you get if you do `console.log(this)`?

Comment: ive posted the image of the object i guess handlebarjs not returning li element

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `this`

```
el = this;
```

Update:

I didn't notice "handlebars.js". Anyway, handlebars js deals with html string. It does not manipulate Objects. You can create templates and apply data to populate the required html string. So if you want to add some data which can be retrieved using jQuery you have to add a property as shown below.

```
<li data-name="abc">abc</li>
```

which can be retrieved using

```
$("li").data("name")
```

I hope the following code will help you
jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/bGJTv/

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('str', function(items, options) {
    var out = '<ul>';

    for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
        out = out + '<li data-mydata="' + items[i].year + '" onclick="onLiClick(event)">' + items[i].firstName + " " + items[i].lastName + '</li>';
    }

    return out + '</ul>';
});



$("#entry-template").html(Handlebars.compile($("#entry-template").html())({
    people: [
        {
        firstName: "Yehuda",
        lastName: "Katz",
        year: "2010"},
    {
        firstName: "Carl",
        lastName: "Lerche",
        year: "2011"},
    {
        firstName: "Alan",
        lastName: "Johnson",
        year: "2012"}
    ]
}));


onLiClick = function (event){
   console.log(event.currentTarget);
    console.log($(event.currentTarget).data("mydata"));
}
```

Comment: but i want to store something like el.data("mydata","2012"); when i do this i get "el.data is not a function"